# Hide and Display of TabPanel in TabContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabpanel

I'm trying to hide the `TabPanel4` when the application start, then when user select specific item from the dropdownlist it then display the `TabPanel4` out for the user. Below is the code I used, not sure why it not working. Do help me take a look at my code see which part did I do wrongly. Thanks!

Aspx

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Height="75%" Width="100%" UseHorizontalStripPlacement="true"
    ActiveTabIndex="0" OnDemand="true" AutoPostBack="true" TabStripPlacement="Top" ScrollBars="Auto">
<asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="Incident Information" Enabled="true" ScrollBars="Auto" OnDemandMode="Once">
<ContentTemplate>
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Type of crime:</b>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlToC" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlToC_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem>Accident</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Theft</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Robbery</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Housebreaking</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Fraud</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Loan Shark</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>

<asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel4" runat="server" HeaderText="Property" Enabled="true" ScrollBars="Auto" OnDemandMode="Once" Visible="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
            Is there any property lost in the incident?
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbPropertyYes" runat="server" GroupName="rbGroup3" Text="Yes" AutoPostBack="True" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="rbPropertyNo" runat="server" GroupName="rbGroup3" Text="No" AutoPostBack="True" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Describe what was lost in the incident." Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProperty" runat="server" Height="75px" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400px" Visible="False"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="You have " Visible="False"></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblCount3" runat="server" Text="500" Visible="False"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text=" characters left." Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

Code behind

```
protected void ddlToC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlToC.SelectedValue.Equals("Theft"))
    {
        TabPanel4.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (ddlToC.SelectedValue.Equals("Robbery"))
    {
        TabPanel4.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (ddlToC.SelectedValue.Equals("Housebreaking"))
    {
        TabPanel4.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (ddlToC.SelectedValue.Equals("Fraud"))
    {
        TabPanel4.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

To add on: even I take away the `Visible="false"` from the aspx page and set it in code behind page under `Page_Load` it don't work, it still don't appear when I select the item in the dropdownlist. Also tried using `TabContainer1.Tabs[3].Visible = false / true;` to hide or display it but it also don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

`ddlToC` is not handling `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Change your markup to this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlToC" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlToC_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Comment: added but it still don't appear after selecting specific item in the dropdownlist

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your conditionals, and see if any of them are evaluating to true.